# How to customize shadow box?

Tags: boxes, shadows

I have the following text box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\definecolor{ShadowColor}{RGB}{30,150,190}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Cshadowbox{\VerbBox\@Cshadowbox}
\def\@Cshadowbox#1{%
  \setbox\@fancybox\hbox{\fbox{#1}}%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \dimen@=\shadowsize
    \advance\dimen@ .5\fboxrule
    \hbox{\copy\@fancybox\kern.5\fboxrule\lower\shadowsize\hbox{%
      \color{ShadowColor}\vrule \@height\ht\@fancybox \@depth\dp\@fancybox \@width\dimen@}}%
    \vskip\dimexpr-\dimen@+0.5\fboxrule\relax
    \moveright\shadowsize\vbox{%
      \color{ShadowColor}\hrule \@width\wd\@fancybox \@height\dimen@}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\colorlet{ShadowColor}{gray}

\Cshadowbox{String1 = String2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How should I do to customize it equal to the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Will all the boxes contain code listings?

Comment: Hello Gonzalo Medina, in fact must enter a String with the text very large identical to the figure with the Boolean operators in bold. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `shadowbox` solution (admitted) but I suggest the `tcolorbox` package and its extreme bunch of options

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{ShadowColor}{RGB}{30,150,190}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Cshadowbox{\VerbBox\@Cshadowbox}
\def\@Cshadowbox#1{%
  \setbox\@fancybox\hbox{\fbox{#1}}%
  \leavevmode\vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip
    \dimen@=\shadowsize
    \advance\dimen@ .5\fboxrule
    \hbox{\copy\@fancybox\kern.5\fboxrule\lower\shadowsize\hbox{%
      \color{ShadowColor}\vrule \@height\ht\@fancybox \@depth\dp\@fancybox \@width\dimen@}}%
    \vskip\dimexpr-\dimen@+0.5\fboxrule\relax
    \moveright\shadowsize\vbox{%
      \color{ShadowColor}\hrule \@width\wd\@fancybox \@height\dimen@}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}



\colorlet{ShadowColor}{gray}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners, drop fuzzy shadow=ShadowColor]
String1 = String2
\end{tcolorbox}

And as listing box: 



   \begin{tcblisting}{listing only,enhanced jigsaw,sharp corners, drop fuzzy shadow=ShadowColor}
String1 = String2

\end{tcblisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Christian Hupfer, that's exactly what I needed, but how should I do to remove the gray background of the text box? The rest is perfect.

Comment: @ricardoramos: You can use the `colback=white` option (replace the colorname by your favourite one) in the `tcolorbox` or `tcblisting` options. (Sorry for the late answer -- I was at the cinema ;-)

Comment: Thank​ you so much for your help Christian Hupfer, now it's all working!

Comment: Key point for future readers.  Don't bother with the big markup in the preamble.  You just require `\usepackage{tcolorbox}` and the part after the begin document that uses tcolorbox.  Other preamble markup is from OP's original failed effort to us fancybox.